# Kext driver cannot find symbol OSPrintBacktrace

Tags: macos, driver, kernel-extension, xnu

I'm using the following function when one of my iokit commands is being called. it defined in

```
extern void OSPrintBacktrace(void);
```

however, my kext seems that my kext fail to load since it couldn't find this symbol..

```
 12/26/16 10:02:53.000 AM kernel[0]: kxld[com.my.driver]: The following symbols are unresolved for this kext:
 12/26/16 10:02:53.000 AM kernel[0]: kxld[com.my.driver]: _OSPrintBacktrace
```

although it does exists in kernel binary

```
 nm /System/Library/Kernels/kernel  | grep OSPrintBacktrace
 ffffff8000837290 T _OSPrintBacktrace
```

Can anybody tell me what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `OSPrintBacktrace` is not part of any of the (public) KPIs. `OSReportWithBacktrace` is however (libkern), so you're probably best off using that. Alternatively, you can also use `OSBacktrace`.